# How can I create a running total for a column in a data frame but skip the first observation?

Tags: r, dplyr, regression

I am trying to create a regression model in R that predicts a golfers score for the next hole.  An input parameter that has proved to be a good indicator of 'what will happen next' is the cumulative scores of the previous hole but I am having trouble adding this column programmatically.  For example, on hole #1 the player's cumulative score is 0, the player takes a 5 on the first hole so the cumulative score for hole #2 is 5 (0 + 5) etc.

I have been able to use dplyr to successfully add a column (cum_score) to the data frame but it isn't quite in the context I need.  My code will start the 'cumulativization' on hole #1 so the cumulative score on hole #1 is 5 in this case when it needs to be zero.  Essentially, I need to skip the first observation and then start the running total.

What I have created using

```
scores <- scores %>% group_by(round_id) %>% mutate(cum_score = cumsum(score))

round_id  score_id  hole_number  score  cum_score
1         100       1            4      4
1         101       2            5      9
1         102       3            4      13
1         103       4            4      17
...
2         150       1            6      6
2         151       2            4      10
...
```

I can get what I want by running the below but then I lose the data for hole #1 and am unsure how to 'plug' just the cum_score column back into the data frame

```
scores %>% group_by(round_id) %>% filter(hole_number > 1) %>% mutate(cum_score = cumsum(score))
```

What I would like to create

```
round_id  score_id  hole_number  score  cum_score
1         100       1            4      0
1         101       2            5      4
1         102       3            4      9
1         103       4            4      13
...
2         150       1            6      0
2         151       2            4      6
...
```

First, thank you for the responses so far, but so far the answers given will just skip the first row.  A better example of the data is below

```
round_id  score_id  hole_number  score  cum_score(what i need)  what the answers output
1         100       1            4      0                        0
1         101       2            4      4                        4
1         102       3            4      8                        8
1         103       4            3      12                       11
1         104       5            4      15                       15
```

Comment: you could use `lag`, like `mutate(cum_score = cumsum(lag(score, default = 0)))`

Comment: Thanks @phiver, but this also gives me the issue of just skipping the first row, I do need it to lag but not lose the score from the first hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways in which you could do this. One way is to ensure the first entry is always 0 and then take `cumsum` of `score` and ignore the last entry.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(round_id) %>%
  mutate(cum_score = c(0, head(cumsum(score), -1)))


#  round_id score_id hole_number score cum_score
#     <int>    <int>       <int> <int>     <dbl>
#1        1      100           1     4         0
#2        1      101           2     5         4
#3        1      102           3     4         9
#4        1      103           4     4        13
#5        2      150           1     6         0
#6        2      151           2     4         6
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(round_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), score_id = 
c(100L,101L, 102L, 103L, 150L, 151L), hole_number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L), score = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L)), .Names = c("round_id", 
"score_id", "hole_number", "score"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, when running it presents me with the same issue as above... An example round I was testing against had the scores of 4 4 4 3 4.  I need the cum_score to be 0 4 8 12 15.  When I run the above code it gives me 0 4 8 11 15.  So really I need the sum of the previous scores, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Dovahkiin Not able to reproduce. When I do `score <- c(4, 4, 4, 3, 4); c(0, head(cumsum(score), -1))` it gives me `0  4  8 12 15` which is same as your expected output.

Comment: You are right, this way does work as expected, apologies and thank you!